# compile directive inside another directive in ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created an example in plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/kcclSc10nPB8Qzm3qr7s?p=preview

there you can see that there is a directive that is adding another directive in the compile function, which works nicely if there is no `ng-if` on the parent `div`. once the `ng-if` is there, the second directive doesn't work anymore. It works with `ng-show` though.

My real scenario is that I need to add a tooltip on some buttons. The tooltip we use is a directive that gets the text to display. The text to display we receive from the backend, based on a key. So it is not an option to go through all of the controllers to call the service to get the text based on the key, then add the text to the scope and give it to the tooltip directive.

One of the buttons is the ok button, which atm is only an image of a checkmark. Only this button occurs in 72 files, so changing everything by hand was not an option. Therefor I looked for the `class="acceptbtn"` in the code and I replaced it with the new directive name and `class="acceptbtn"`. So now all the buttons have my directive that gets the key. Inside my directive I get the text based on the key I pass, and I add to this element the tooltip directive with the text I receive.

This works nicely in some of the cases. Problem is that it doesn't work if there is a wrapper `div` with `ng-if`. Looking for all the `ng-if`s in all these files would also not be an option (unless there is no other option).

So is there a way to fix this? Meaning, in the plnkr, the third div should look like the second one. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working  [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/z0zXM69KyuiD2GNTB5Ln?p=preview)

```
app.directive('dir1', function($compile){
return{
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
         element.removeAttr('dir1');
         element.attr('dir2', '');
         $compile(element)(scope);
      }
}
});

app.directive('dir2', function($compile){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       element.removeAttr('dir2');
       element.attr('style', "width:400px");
       $compile(element)(scope);
    }
    };
});
```

I slightly modified your directives, using the link function. I personally only use compilation when there are runtime changes to my directive templates.

Comment: awesome, it works! I only changed the first directive, since I didn't have access to the second one. But it works like that too. Could you please edit a bit your answer to briefly explain what happened, what the difference is? Thanks